# Generic slideshow getting started

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, timer

This is a getting started question about how to create a reusable wpf slideshow control:

- that displays a sequence of any visualizable elements e.g. a series of Image controls or a series of UserControls (**should I target `ContentControl`, or is there a broader type that encompasses more visualizables/controls?**)
- the control should be able to **accept an `IList` of some kind**, which would be the elements/slides to present
- the control should expose an Interval property that determines the duration of each slide, but i dont even know the basics of how to get started with that in terms of **offering that property to be configured in xaml**?
- and **what should the container be, if any, for the individual slides/controls that are passed in**?

Comment: Do you need animation? If not it's a lot easier.

Comment: in the first instance no animation is required ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you should probably create a `UserControl` which contains an `Image` control, and perhaps Next/Previous `Buttons`, and anything else you may need. These would all be laid out as normal using a variety of panels, you could probably style most of it with just a Grid.

After that, your `UserControl` will implement the `ImageSource` (your `IList`, or `IEnumerable` of images), and your interval as dependency properties. These are then settable in XAML.

You would then write the logic which loads the next image and sets it as the Image's `Source` property, this could happen in the change event for the `ImageSource` property. You can then get as advanced as you wish with Image preloading/caching etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer! 1) where could i learn about how to create the dependency property for Interval? 2) im interested in creating a generic slideshow control that works with more than just Image controls (e.g. it woudl be able to show whole UserControls given to it as the slides), hence my question about whether to use `ContentControl` or something else?

Comment: Yes, you could use a ContentControl if you wish the slideshow to be generic. The Interval dependency property will just store the interval value, when the value changes, you can reset a Timer for example. Dependency properties are explained here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've just delved into WPF myself for a "Slideshow" like project where I'm showing customer order numbers on screen for a period of time before showing the next, and using Effect/Transitions/Storyboards to move to the next frame. I found a good article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfPageTransitions.aspx)

I used a Grid with 2 rows:

1. Contains my "Changing area".
2. Contains static information (logo, controls etc).

Rememeber to set "cliptobounds = true" on your changing area if you use any sort of transforms on it. (I know you said you aren't using transitions initially, but once people see it, they'll be asking).

Dependency properties are also easily built in C# if you just type `propdp` and hit tab.

Comment: thanks for a great link and tips - id choose yours as an answer but devdigital answered first...